# How to filter posts with no comments

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Let's get to the problem.
I have a view that is supposed to show me all unanswered questions, that were asked later 4 hours. I' ve already tried a lot but it didn't work, so i ask this.
What should I do to filter posts without comments

views.py

```
def subject_unanswered(request, slug):
    subject = Subject.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    four_hours = datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=4)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(subject=subject, created_at__lt=four_hours).order_by('-created_at')
    args = {
        'subject'       : subject,
        'posts'         : posts,
        }
    return render(request, 'ask/subject_time_ago.html', args)
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    related_post    = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment         = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    created_by      = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    created_at      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes           = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name='comment_likes', blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    slug        = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    subject     = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic       = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text        = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    created_by  = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes       = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name='likes', blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter by reverse relations like

```
Post.objects.filter(comment__isnull=True)
```

this should return all posts without comments.